# Percentages within dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

```
dict1 = {'Milky': ['yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no'],
         'Chocolate': ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no']  }  

for j in dict1:
```

Chocolate and Milky are conditions (in experiment) and `'yes'` or `'no'` were they responses for each trial.

I would like to calculate the percentage of `'yes'` in the milky condition (`2 / 5 * 100`) and the chocolate condition, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Easy. Get the number of "yes" responses, divide by the total number of responses, multiply that by 100.

Comment: That's what I've been trying to do, but the code doesn't seem to work. Do you have code for this?

Comment: @Anonypy: What code do you have that doesn't seem to be working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would create a percentage function:

```
def percentage(of, in_):
    return in_.count(of) * 100 / len(in_)
```

and then apply that in a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> dct = {'Milky': ['yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no'], 
...        'Chocolate': ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no']}
>>>
>>> {key: percentage('yes', values) for key, values in dct.items()}
{'Chocolate': 60.0, 'Milky': 40.0}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I am aiming to have the percentage for chocolate and the percentage for milky in two separate variables. Is this possible?

Comment: just save the result in a variable: `result = {key: percentage(value, 'yes') for key, value in dct.items()}` and to get the values access `result['Milky']` or `result['Chocolate']`.

Comment: Nitpick: I'd rename `inp` and `search`. It's not instantly clear what they are.

Comment: Hey yeah I just looped through and used an 'if' statement. Thanks!

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson You're right, I wasn't very creative at the time, I hope they're better now.